# Can we specify the working zone for the robot using SLAM approach for navigation?

Tags: slam

I am using SLAM for the autonomous vehicle navigation.

I want to the specify the working zone for the vehicle before the start of navigation, or can we restrict the working zone of the vehicle using SLAM approach for navigation.

Answer (score 1):

In theory that is possible. A SLAM (*Simultaneous localization and mapping*) algorithm, as the name suggests, will build a map of the environment and infer the vehicles position in that environment. Based on that information it should be possible to limit a vehicles navigation to a certain "working zone".

In practice the properties of the operational environment in combination with what vehicles, sensors and SLAM algorithms are used will determine if and what kind of "working zones" can be enforced. But without further information it is impossible to make a statement about any more concrete practical implications.